# Where do I put test-related files in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a fair amount of unit tests for my python libraries, and many of them require some other non-code files to run. For example, to test a file parser, I may have a few example files to parse.

All of these test-related files currently reside in a directory parallel to the test code directory but I'm curious if there's an accepted practice and/or location for such auxiliary data?

Comment: I know pyinstaller has a directory called tests: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/develop/tests. I don't think it can be more basic than that.

Comment: For the test code I do have a directory called tests. I'm curious about whether it's good practice to put non-python files there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is rather opinion/habit question. However, tests should be independent and should form a concise package without too many outgoing dependencies. Therefore in your case I'd organize the directory structure like this:

```
test files:
tests/

tests resources:
tests/dataSets/testfixture1/
tests/dataSets/testfixture2/
etc.
```

or

```
test files:
tests/

tests resources:
tests/testfixture1Data/
tests/testfixture2Data/
etc.
```

or something similar.
This way you can keep tests independent as the structure does not encourage test data re-usage. Also, everything is located in one place, which increases readability.